# Application-defined or object -defined error with active range

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I am using the VBA code below were SpRatings is the name of a named range (created with an offset formula that gives me a column of different heights depending on the number of items contained). When i was running this code with a non-active range, it seemed to work. Can somebody advise on how to fix it for it to work?

I strictly need to have the for loop looping through an active range.

```
With ActiveChart

 Set Serpo = .SeriesCollection(11).Points

        'Save the number of points in chart to variable j
        j = Serpo.Count

        'Iterate though each point in current series
        For i = 1 To j

            'Enable data label for current chart point
            Serpo(i).ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlShowValue

            'Save cell reference to chart point
            Serpo(i).DataLabel.Formula = "=" & Range("SpRatings").Cells(i).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
            Serpo(i).DataLabel.Font.ColorIndex = 2
            Serpo(i).DataLabel.Position = xlLabelPositionInsideBase
        Next
End With
```

Comment: actually no. it does not work with a non-active range either. same error

Comment: We need more detail on how you are setting up `Range("SpRatings")`.

Comment: @GM13 When you get the error, what is your `i`?  You're positive that your named range has the same count to your data labels/points?

Comment: You haven't mentioned which line throws the error? Also, it would be useful to see a sample of your chart